# is disabling ETAG and Last-Modifed a good option .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using the below code for caching of files in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(css|scss)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|xml)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
    #Header unset ETag
    #Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
```

I'm a bit confused if i should comment the `#Header unset ETag` and `#Header unset Last-Modified` or not

below is my default.conf file on apache

```
CacheQuickHandler off                                                                                              
CacheLock on
CacheLockPath /tmp/mod_cache-lock
CacheLockMaxAge 5                                                                                                  
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
<Location />                                                                                                       
CacheEnable disk                                                                                                   
CacheHeader on                                                                                                     
CacheDefaultExpire 600                                                                                             
CacheMaxExpire 86400
CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.5                                                                                        
ExpiresActive on                                                                                                   
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"                                                                                
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"                                                                   
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"                                                                      
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"                                                                      
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"                                                                       
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/ld+json "acesss plus 1 day"                                                              
# This part sets the expires for the fonts                                                                         
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"                                                                   
#Header merge Cache-Control public
FileETag All                                                                                                       
</Location>
```

Kindly anyone help me with this confusion what should i do to achieve maximum and best compression.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? ETags and Last-Modified headers help with cache invalidation.

Comment: then doesn't this line suffice it? `Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"`

Comment: Please avoid unneccessary tags - this question has no connection to PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Etag` and `Last-Modified` have nothing to do with compression, they are cache'ing options. Which is OK to unset anyway because they conflict with `Cache-Control`, which is a better cache method. So yes, you may disable it.

If you are looking for compression, look into Apache's `mod_deflate`, `mod_gzip` or `mod_brotli`.

Comment: should i add this code to the .htaccess as well?

`# This is for gzip, which compresses files
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>`

Comment: My advice is to not copy paste code you don't understand. But what that code does is turn on gzip compression for html, txt, css, js, php, pl, text files. While excluding already compressed images. Just make to sure to enable `mod_gzip` in Apache first or you will get a syntax error.

Comment: mod_gzip is enabled

Comment: Then it will work, your responses will be compressed.

Comment: should i use the mod_gzip codes with the above question code in .htacces?

Comment: The compression  code does not conflict with the cache code, so leave it as it is. Keep it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209937/discussion-between-akshay-shrivastav-and-jon-frenchtoast).